# Jsp page takes too much time in edge but works in chrome browser and incognito mode

Tags: java, jsp, caching, microsoft-edge

I am working on a jsp web application, There is a jsp page which has datatable that has too many records , but the page loads quickly in **chrome** or in **incognito mode of edge** . But when I tried to load it in the **normal edge browser** It takes lot of time,
Also there is a extension called **Microsoft editor** If I disable it then the page loads faster. But this is not the actual solution .

I have tried adding

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
 <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
```

in the jsp page. Can someone tell me the reason behind this

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache, it might work for you. And as you mentioned, disable the browser extension, they also have some impact on page loading speed..

Comment: @XudongPeng I tried that but still the same issue

Comment: What is your version of Edge? You can try to reinstall it or repair it, this maybe work for you.

Comment: @XudongPeng I am using 96.0.1054.62 version and the browser is managed by the organization so I don't have the option to repair it